# Should I use the minus sign when writing papers in characteristic two

Tags: soft-question, notation

Is there any consensus regarding whether one should write both "+" and "-" or only "+" when performing computations in characteristic two fields?

To give some context, I am writing my thesis, which largely considers curves over fields of positive characteristic $p > 0$. Often a result holds for $p >2$, and then there is an analogous result for $p = 2$.

Generally these analogous results will be placed in the same statement, or one immediately after the other. Hence I worry that only using "+" will be confusing for someone who is skimming through - saying something like "$a+b = c$ and hence $a = b + c$" may at least cause some momentary confusion. Also, in some cases it feels that the analogy between $p=2$ and $p >2$ is not as clear when replacing "-" by "+".

On the other hand, it does seem redundant to use both "+" and "-", and redundancy is not something mathematicians are keen on.

Overall I feel that in some instances I would prefer to use only "+", such as if the whole piece were in characteristic two, so I wondered whether this is a standard in anyway.

Comment: I would use a minus if there would be a minus in the corresponding statement in other characteristics, e.g. if I were writing "$a - b = 0$ and therefore $a = b$."

Comment: This is what I had been largely doing (though I am not sure how consciously). But you wouldn't find it unusual either way?

Comment: It's a stylistic call, honestly. Quiaochu's comment is probably the best rule of thumb. You're a professional now, you get to make judgment calls based on your own aesthetic. Enjoy it!

Comment: Ah, but one exception is if there are sign issues I'm deliberately ignoring by working in characteristic $2$, e.g. when writing down differentials or doing intersection theory. It doesn't sound like that applies to your case though. (By the way, I don't buy your redundancy argument. Don't think about redundancy; focus on clarity. The point of writing is to be understood.)